# Hiding the navigation on a modal pop-up box on SharePoint 2013 Enterprise

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, development, web-part, navigation

Is there a way to prevent the navigation from appearing twice on the page with modal pop-up boxes as seen in the image below?

[image: Double Navigation]

I'm aware you can change the css to display none but I would only want that option when the navigation is duplicated. The pop-up in the image is using a web part but I have also noticed this with document uploading. Is there a way to prevent the navigation tag from appearing more than once on the page?

Answer (score 2):

There is default SharePoint CSS class available that you can use.

`ms-dialogHidden` is the class when you don't want particular `div` or any element to appear on the dialog.

So simply specify extra class to the navigation div `ms-dialogHidden`.

Comment: it seems to hide more consistently on the DeltaTopNavigation div ID which is attached to the ms-displayInline div class. I'm appending s4-nodlg to the tag, how should this be added to the page(s)?

Comment: Can you show your snippet what you done so far?